# Can you enforce uniqueness in MySQL based on column in foreign table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, unique-constraint

I am refactoring one of my database tables and I've come up with an issue.

Specifically, I have a table with four columns. We'll call the first three `my.a`, `my.b` and `my.c`.  I have a uniqueness constraint on the combination of these three columns.  Column `my.d` is a foreign key to an auto-incremented ID column in another table `foreign`.

I realized that this other table *also* has a column `foreign.a` and both column `a`s are complete duplicates, i.e., if you join the tables together on `d`, `my.a` will always equal `foreign.a`.  Apparently this is part of the requirements.

I would like to remove column `my.a` from my table, but that will remove the uniqueness constraint.  Is there a way to somehow set up a uniqueness constraint on the combination of `foreign.a, my.b, my.c`?  Or am I better off just leaving the duplicate column in place?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to remove the `my.a` column and keep the uniqueness constraint. But another thing you can do, is replacing the foreign key `my (d) references foreign (d)` with  `my (a,d) references foreign (a,d)` so what your know see in the database (both column as are complete duplicates) is guaranteed by the database itself.

Comment: Yup, I was definitely going to do that if there was no way to get rid of `my.a`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly create a unique constraint across tables. I say directly because you could come up with some indirect scheme; what comes to my mind would be using triggers to insert into a third table that has the unique constraint. But that's a lot of extra work compared to the obvious solution, which is to keep the column "a" in the "my" table.